# Remember Me in Devise fails to Login User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, hotwire

If I don't use `remember_me` option, it works perfectly fine. The app flows as expected.

However, if I check `remember_me`, it will login in as expected, redirect me to a protected page, which will then redirect me back to the `sign_in` page (Since I use `before_action :authenticate_user!`. One other thing that `user_signed_in?` will retrun false as well).

---

Here is the request cycle.
[image]

---

Here is the logs dump

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-06-08 22:33:44 +0500
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"email"=>"example@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "example@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/projects
Completed 303 See Other in 253ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms | Allocations: 2776)


Started GET "/projects" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-06-08 22:33:44 +0500
Processing by ProjectsController#index as TURBO_STREAM
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 356)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-06-08 22:33:44 +0500
Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as TURBO_STREAM
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 230)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 2.5ms | Allocations: 1060)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 47)
  Rendered layouts/_flash.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 20)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 6.7ms | Allocations: 3860)
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 7.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 4622)
```

---

As for my `Gemfile

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.2.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem 'sprockets-rails'

# Use pg as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'

# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps [https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails]
gem 'importmap-rails'

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem 'turbo-rails'

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem 'stimulus-rails'

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem 'jbuilder'

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', require: false

# Use Sass to process CSS
# gem "sassc-rails"

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem 'debug', platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
  gem 'rubocop'
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem 'web-console'

  # Annotate database models
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'rails-erd'

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Custom Gems
gem 'acts_as_list', '~> 1.1'
gem 'acts_as_recursive_tree', '~> 3.3'
gem 'cssbundling-rails', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.2'
gem 'date_validator', '~> 0.12.0'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.9', '>= 4.9.2'
gem 'name_of_person', '~> 1.1'
gem 'pay', '~> 6.3'
gem 'requestjs-rails'
gem 'responders', '~> 3.1'
gem 'stripe', '~> 8.5'
```

---

I am just so confused, could be due to timezone issues? Or possibly some other misconfiguration?

---

**UPDATE:**
Here is my devise config (removed all the comments)

```rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = 'hey@example.com'

  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]

  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]

  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 12

  config.reconfirmable = true

  config.remember_for = 2.weeks

  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true

  config.password_length = 6..128

  config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/

  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours

  config.sign_out_via = :get

  config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :turbo_stream]

  config.responder.error_status = :unprocessable_entity
  config.responder.redirect_status = :see_other
end
```

The `sessions_controller` is just empty. I didn't override anything.

```rb
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_in_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
  # end
end
```

The only changes I made were to `registrations_controller`.

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/edit
  # def edit
  #   super
  # end

  # PUT /resource
  # def update
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  # def cancel
  #   super
  # end

  protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_up_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name])
  end

  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    edit_user_registration_path(resource)
  end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts.
  # def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end
end
```

Here is my `Gemfile.lock`

```
GIT
  remote: https://github.com/rails/rails.git
  revision: 55c3066da325703ff7a9524dbdc479b860db3970
  branch: main
  specs:
    actioncable (7.1.0.alpha)
      actionpack (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activesupport (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.6)
    actionmailbox (7.1.0.alpha)
      actionpack (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activejob (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activerecord (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activestorage (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activesupport (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
    actionmailer (7.1.0.alpha)
      actionpack (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      actionview (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activejob (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activesupport (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (7.1.0.alpha)
      actionview (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activesupport (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
      rack (>= 2.2.4)
      rack-session (>= 1.0.1)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.6)
    actiontext (7.1.0.alpha)
      actionpack (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activerecord (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activestorage (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activesupport (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      globalid (>= 0.6.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (7.1.0.alpha)
      activesupport (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.11)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.6)
    activejob (7.1.0.alpha)
      activesupport (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (7.1.0.alpha)
      activesupport (= 7.1.0.alpha)
    activerecord (7.1.0.alpha)
      activemodel (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activesupport (= 7.1.0.alpha)
    activestorage (7.1.0.alpha)
      actionpack (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activejob (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activerecord (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activesupport (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      marcel (~> 1.0)
    activesupport (7.1.0.alpha)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      connection_pool (>= 2.2.5)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
    rails (7.1.0.alpha)
      actioncable (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      actionmailbox (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      actionmailer (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      actionpack (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      actiontext (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      actionview (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activejob (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activemodel (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activerecord (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activestorage (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activesupport (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 7.1.0.alpha)
    railties (7.1.0.alpha)
      actionpack (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      activesupport (= 7.1.0.alpha)
      irb
      rackup (>= 1.0.0)
      rake (>= 12.2)
      thor (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.2)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.6)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    acts_as_list (1.1.0)
      activerecord (>= 4.2)
    acts_as_recursive_tree (3.4.0)
      activerecord (>= 5.2.0, < 8)
      activesupport (>= 5.2.0, < 8)
      zeitwerk (>= 2.4)
    addressable (2.8.4)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 6.0)
    annotate (3.2.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.2, < 8.0)
      rake (>= 10.4, < 14.0)
    ast (2.4.2)
    bcrypt (3.1.18)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.16.0)
      msgpack (~> 1.2)
    builder (3.2.4)
    capybara (3.39.1)
      addressable
      matrix
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    choice (0.2.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.2.2)
    connection_pool (2.4.1)
    crass (1.0.6)
    cssbundling-rails (1.1.2)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    date (3.3.3)
    date_validator (0.12.0)
      activemodel (>= 3)
      activesupport (>= 3)
    debug (1.8.0)
      irb (>= 1.5.0)
      reline (>= 0.3.1)
    devise (4.9.2)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubi (1.12.0)
    globalid (1.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
    i18n (1.14.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    importmap-rails (1.1.6)
      actionpack (>= 6.0.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    io-console (0.6.0)
    irb (1.7.0)
      reline (>= 0.3.0)
    jbuilder (2.11.5)
      actionview (>= 5.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    json (2.6.3)
    loofah (2.21.3)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.12.0)
    mail (2.8.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
    marcel (1.0.2)
    matrix (0.4.2)
    mini_mime (1.1.2)
    minitest (5.18.0)
    msgpack (1.7.1)
    name_of_person (1.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 5.2.0)
    net-imap (0.3.4)
      date
      net-protocol
    net-pop (0.1.2)
      net-protocol
    net-protocol (0.2.1)
      timeout
    net-smtp (0.3.3)
      net-protocol
    nio4r (2.5.9)
    nokogiri (1.15.2-aarch64-linux)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    nokogiri (1.15.2-x86_64-linux)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    parallel (1.23.0)
    parser (3.2.2.1)
      ast (~> 2.4.1)
    pay (6.6.1)
      rails (>= 6.0.0)
    pg (1.5.3)
    public_suffix (5.0.1)
    puma (5.6.5)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.6.2)
    rack (3.0.7)
    rack-session (2.0.0)
      rack (>= 3.0.0)
    rack-test (2.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.3)
    rackup (2.1.0)
      rack (>= 3)
      webrick (~> 1.8)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-erd (1.7.2)
      activerecord (>= 4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
      choice (~> 0.2.0)
      ruby-graphviz (~> 1.2)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.6.0)
      loofah (~> 2.21)
      nokogiri (~> 1.14)
    rainbow (3.1.1)
    rake (13.0.6)
    redis (4.8.1)
    regexp_parser (2.8.0)
    reline (0.3.5)
      io-console (~> 0.5)
    requestjs-rails (0.0.10)
      rails (>= 6.0.0)
    responders (3.1.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      railties (>= 5.2)
    rexml (3.2.5)
    rubocop (1.52.0)
      json (~> 2.3)
      parallel (~> 1.10)
      parser (>= 3.2.0.0)
      rainbow (>= 2.2.2, < 4.0)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.8, < 3.0)
      rexml (>= 3.2.5, < 4.0)
      rubocop-ast (>= 1.28.0, < 2.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
      unicode-display_width (>= 2.4.0, < 3.0)
    rubocop-ast (1.29.0)
      parser (>= 3.2.1.0)
    ruby-graphviz (1.2.5)
      rexml
    ruby-progressbar (1.13.0)
    rubyzip (2.3.2)
    selenium-webdriver (4.10.0)
      rexml (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.5)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2, < 3.0)
      websocket (~> 1.0)
    sprockets (4.2.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (>= 2.2.4, < 4)
    sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    stimulus-rails (1.2.1)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    stripe (8.5.0)
    thor (1.2.2)
    timeout (0.3.2)
    turbo-rails (1.4.0)
      actionpack (>= 6.0.0)
      activejob (>= 6.0.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.6)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    unicode-display_width (2.4.2)
    warden (1.2.9)
      rack (>= 2.0.9)
    web-console (4.2.0)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (5.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 4.0)
    webrick (1.8.1)
    websocket (1.2.9)
    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.6.8)

PLATFORMS
  aarch64-linux
  x86_64-linux

DEPENDENCIES
  acts_as_list (~> 1.1)
  acts_as_recursive_tree (~> 3.3)
  annotate
  bootsnap
  capybara
  cssbundling-rails (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.2)
  date_validator (~> 0.12.0)
  debug
  devise (~> 4.9, >= 4.9.2)
  importmap-rails
  jbuilder
  name_of_person (~> 1.1)
  pay (~> 6.3)
  pg (~> 1.1)
  puma (~> 5.0)
  rails!
  rails-erd
  redis (~> 4.0)
  requestjs-rails
  responders (~> 3.1)
  rubocop
  selenium-webdriver
  sprockets-rails
  stimulus-rails
  stripe (~> 8.5)
  turbo-rails
  tzinfo-data
  web-console
  webdrivers

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.2.1p31

BUNDLED WITH
   2.4.12
```

Comment: Please post your Devise controllers and config

Comment: @r-sierra I have added the config.

Comment: Can you add the versions  for Rails, devise and turbo-rails ?

Comment: @r-sierra I added my `Gemfile.lock` content as well.

Comment: Since this feature works in other versions of Rails, you might want to try in Rails 7.0.5, just to confirm it is not an issue with the Rails 7.1.0.alpha version you are using. Just a thought.

Comment: @C.Smith, Yep. Found it. The problem is with Rails `7.1.0.alpha`. It works fine on Rails `7.0.5`. Is there anything that I can do to make it work or do I have to wait for the public release of `7.1`?

Comment: Personally, I would not use the alpha version. It is not ready for production. You should submit an Issue to devise thought